# RHEL ways to simulate or virtualize time

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, time

I am trying to get my machine to simulate or visualize time without changing system time so that I can run code under simulated/virtual time so that my timestamps are in the past and such.

I know faketime is an option but the bug seems to be an issue (regarding statically linked programs) among other things.

Does anyone know of any other options? Thanks!

Comment: There is now a `time` namespace which you might be interested in, but iirc it can only move you into the future, and things outside the namespace will just see the "normal" time.

Comment: A virtual machine has its own kernel and therefore its own system time, which you can set to a point in the past.

Comment: Have you tried `faketime` to see if it works in your situation?

Comment: @roaima yes and ive been testing with it, but I unfortunately have some weird issue where it doesn't output my chronyc sources call. On an identical computer, it does however.

Comment: @cryptarch Unfortunately, I need to go into the past. Like Epoch onwards